# Raspberry Piv2 Camera NoIR displays pink colors in video feed!

Tags: pi-2

I want to ask that I have a piv2 NoIR camera that gives pink colors in a camera stream running live on my Jetson Nano, So I want my piv2 camera to display normal colors then what can I do? Do i need to change the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want normal colours then you need a camera with an IR filter so the answer is yes, of course it won't work too well at night then.